# How to create common model to inherit from in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to convert all my models in a rails app to use uuid as id and maybe if I need, add some fields that will be common to all my models. To do this I am thinking of, instead of doing this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

doing this

```
class CommonUUIDModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  some_uuid_related_information
end

class MyModel < CommonUUIDModel
end
```

my questions are:
How can I achieve this (what should be in the place of **some_uuid_related_information** and is this a good practice for Rails applications?

Answer (score 0):

Prefer extension (mixing in modules) to inheritance (subclasses).

In other words, make a module that alters the models in a uniform way and include that module in all classes that use it.

This is especially true of ActiveRecord-backed models, since subclassing often signals STI (single table inheritance)